# Order Specific Character in SQL server

Tags: sql, mariadb

I use mariadb, this code for the table `CREATE TABLE a( version_id varchar(10) );`

I got the following entry from table a in my database:

> 10.1.
> 10.10.
> 10.11.
> 10.12.
> 10.2.
> 10.3.
> 10.4.
> 10.5.
> 10.6.
> 10.7.
> 10.8.
> 10.9.

I want to order the entry so I get:

> 10.1.
> 10.2.
> 10.3.
> 10.4.
> 10.5.
> 10.6.
> 10.7.
> 10.8.
> 10.9.
> 10.10.
> 10.11.
> 10.12.

How can I solve it?

Comment: What's the data type of the column, can you provide the ddl

Comment: What actual SQL have you tried that you can actually post IN the question that we can help you with?  Please also post code that shows your table(s) and columns (with the types) so we can properly help you here.

Comment: @Umar.H I am using string data type for this column

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I am sorry for that, I use mariadb, this code for the table CREATE TABLE a(
  version_id varchar(10)
);

Comment: I've reopened this question because it is [about MariaDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75987803/order-specific-character-in-sql-server?noredirect=1#comment134021512_75987803) *not* Oracle (and the tag was amended to SQL Server?), neither of which were *ever* tagged. As a non-SME (of MariaDB) I don't want to reclose this as a dupe of a different question, but I'm sure a gold badger can find one.

Comment: I have voted to once again close this since there is no attempted SQL in the question.  Good update to add the table however there!.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can sort by the number extracted from your string:

```
select *
from mytable
order by CAST(REPLACE(version_id, '.', '') AS INT)
```

This will handle mixed versions (`10.*, 20.* ...` ) :

```
select *
from mytable
order by CAST(REPLACE(version_id, '.', '') + REPLICATE('0', 5-LEN(REPLACE(version_id, '.', ''))) AS INT)
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/lDfwsfVI)

Comment: This does not really answer the question since the OP posted nothing related to/about the database structure or any attempt and thus this is likely just a wild guess which may or may NOT resolve the issue.

Please don't encourage poorly asked questions with answers without more information from the OP.

Comment: Thanks very much, It works for me, I thought it might be the ORDER BY CASE but have never used it before and the other stuff I read on it didn't seem to fit exactly. Awesome!

Comment: If you add a value like `'20.2.'` then this is likely going to produce wrong results too. `'202'` is less than `'1010'`

Comment: Good remark @ThomA, I have made it more general https://dbfiddle.uk/lDfwsfVI

Comment: Will this really work on Mariadb?

Comment: @jarlh No, this is Sql server, its mentioned in the title, someone have changed the tag to mariadb

Comment: Why don't remove just the trailing point and convert the value to double ? `ORDER BY TRIM("." FROM version_id) + 0`

Answer (score 0):

We can remove the trailing point and convert the value to double using `TRIM`:

```
select *
from mytable
order by TRIM("." FROM version_id) + 0
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/2osg7Nnd)